# Advanced Filter to copy on another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a few problems with my VBA Code.
This is what I want to do:

1. Take the path from a sheet (input)
2. Open the related workbook
3. Use advanced filter to copy only the needed columns of the over 60 of the opened file to the original file.
4. Close file

I know the code is partly hard-coded so far and has some bloat, but please ignore it.

When I run the vba I get a runtime error 438. (property or method not supported) in the advanced filter line.

This is my code:

```
Public strFileName As String
Public currentWB As Workbook
Public dataWB As Workbook
Public strCopyRange As String
Public rngFiltro As Variant

Sub PrendiDati()
    Dim strListSheet As String
    Dim rngFonte As Variant


    strListSheet = "input"

    'On Error GoTo ErrH
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SCADENZIARIO").Range("A2:R15000").Clear
    Sheets(strListSheet).Select
    Range("b6").Select

    'this is the main loop, we will open the files one by one and copy their data into the masterdata sheet
    Set currentWB = ActiveWorkbook
        strFileName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & ActiveCell.Value
        strCopyRange = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
        strWhereToCopy = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
        strStartCellColName = Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5), 2, 1)
        Application.Workbooks.Open strFileName, UpdateLinks:=False
        Set dataWB = ActiveWorkbook
        dataWB.Worksheet(1).Range("Database").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=currentWB.Sheets("SCADENZIARIO").Range("A1")
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        dataWB.Close False
        Sheets(strListSheet).Select
        Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```
dataWB.Worksheet(1)
```

Should be:

```
dataWB.Worksheets(1)
```

The error raises because there is now `Worksheet` property/method for the `Workbook` object.

Comment: Thank you!
I really should have noticed.